# Terraform manual approval stage in gitlab ci for terraform

Tags: terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I was trying to implement a manual approval for Terraform apply using Gitlab CI. Here is my code:

```
manual_approval:
  stage: manual_approval
  before_script:
  script:
    - terraform plan -input=false -out=tfplan
     - if terraform show tfplan | grep -q "No changes"; then echo "No changes"; CHANGES="false"; echo $CHANGES >> manual_approval.env; elif terraform show tfplan| grep -q "0 to change, 0 to destroy"; then echo "no destroys"; CHANGES="false"; echo $CHANGES >> manual_approval.env; else CHANGES="true"; echo $CHANGES >> manual_approval.env; fi
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: manual_approval.env  
wait_for_approval:
  stage: wait_for_approval
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "$CHANGES"
  allow_failure: false 
  rules: 
    - if: ($CHANGES == "true")
  dependencies:
    - manual_approval
terraform_apply:
  stage: terraform_apply
```

The manual approval stage will pop up based on the value of CHANGES. but this stage is not showing in my pipeline. I know that rules are evaluated before any jobs run. Does anybody have any other suggestions for this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone help me here?

Comment: yes, am also looking for a similar steps for my pipeline, is anybody can help here?